# How to find button element within table column using selenium webdriver

Tags: python, html, selenium

I am writing a script for clicking a button on a webpage which will eventually download a file. However the button object is located within the column element of a table.
Using python with selenium bindings for the same.

Here is the script in python:

```
element_found = browser_open.find_elements_by_xpath("//form[@name='xxxx']/div[@id='xxxx']/div[@id='xxxx']/div[@id='xxxxx']/div[@id='xxxxx']/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[9]/")
```

The problem is I am not able to access the button element within this column and when i print the element:

```
for element in element_found:
    print (element.get_attribute('id'))
```

It is always printing null.

This is the HTML script for the button I am trying to download:

```
    <input name="xxxx" id="yyyyy" title="Export (CSV)"     class="toolbar_button_csv toolbar_button_csv_mousedown toolbar_button_csv_mouseup" usesubmitbehavior="false" onmousedown="$(this).addClass('toolbar_button_csv_mousedown'); return true;" onmouseup="$(this).addClass('toolbar_button_csv_mouseup'); return true;" src="/CqUtpSms/Handlers/Master/Expires.ashx?version=1.16.1.1030&amp;url=%xx.gif" onclick="Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_pageLoaded(xx);" style="height:16px;width:16px;border-width:0px;margin-right:5px;" type="image">
```

Could some one please help me to understand how to click on the button which is embedded in the column position of a table within a web page?

Is there a way where I can download the button without knowing the element?

Appreciate for the help.

Comment: Please post the HTML representation of the table including the button. Thanks.

Comment: <input name="xxxx" id="yyyyy" title="Export (CSV)" class="toolbar_button_csv toolbar_button_csv_mousedown toolbar_button_csv_mouseup" usesubmitbehavior="false" onmousedown="$(this).addClass('toolbar_button_csv_mousedown');  return true;" onmouseup="$(this).addClass('toolbar_button_csv_mouseup');  return true;" src="/CqUtpSms/Handlers/Master/Expires.ashx?version=1.16.1.1030&amp;url=%2fCqUtpSms%2fThemes%2fIntel%2fImages%2fLayout%2ftrans.gif" onclick="Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_pageLoaded(xx);" style="height:16px;width:16px;border-width:0px;margin-right:5px;" type="image">

Comment: Please edit your question and post it there instead of using comments. Thanks.

Comment: added to the query thanks....